Перезагрузка браузера при запуске функции на back-end
Ситуация следующаяя:
Есть приложение на html/css/js - front-end
И есть серверная часть на python - back-end.
На серврере реализована функция подключения по WebSocket к сторонней платформе и получение данных от неё каждые 250мс и так же функция которая обрабатывает эти данные, и есть резальтат обработки удовлетворяет фильтру, отправляется уведомление на клиента (front-end).
Так вот, при запуске этого блока на сервере, начинает происходить постоянная перезагрузка страницы.
С чем это связано?
И как это можно решить ?

Судя по описанию, все работает как раз так, как задумано.

Да, но страница не должна обновляться. Потому что это вызывает закрытие ws соединения для уведомлений со сторны клиента в итоге.

ну тут вряд ли есть телепаты, которые, не зная кода, смогут вам ответить на ваши вопросы.

Похожий вопрос - смотрите обработчик ответа от сервера.
